# How to create index in mongodb server using laravel mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

In my laravel mongodb application I am trying to create a index to the mongodb server using following code:

```
DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('products_', $project->id_project)->createIndex(['id' => 1]);
```

But I got an error:

Call to undefined method Jenssegers\Mongodb\Query\Builder::createIndex()

BTW, I am using this package: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb